# Generic interface constructor injection asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

The interface:

```
IRepository<T> {}
```

and the implementation:

```
Repository<T> : IRepository<T> {}
```

Constructor:

```
public HomeController(IRepository<T> repository)
{
...
}
```

I'm using Unity container with custom controller factory.

For route **/customers** constructor should be using

```
Repository<Customer>
```

for route **/products**

```
Repository<Product>
```

**How to make it working?**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a post on Auto-registration, I haven't tried this, but solves the problem you have:

http://marcinbudny.blogspot.com/2009/11/unity-auto-registration.html

Comment: I think this is better, but I don't understand everything http://www.agileatwork.com/unit-of-work-with-unity-and-aspnet-mvc/